# I need to Uncheck the other radio buttons that holding same class (of course they are NOT in the same group),

Tags: jquery

when i check a radio button I need to Uncheck the other radio buttons that holding same class (of course they are not at the same group) using siblings . So when I click on a radio then  All others in different group must Uncheck How Can i do that ? `

```
   $('.RRFrom').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().prop('checked', false);
});
```

`

```html
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4">
<input class="form-check-input  RRFrom RRFromRow2" type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow2[]" id="RRFromRow2" value="RR" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="RRFromRow2" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer">Rail Road</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4 ">
<input class="form-check-input ChassiFromRow2" type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow2[]" id="ChassiFromRow2" value="ZZ" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="ChassiFromRow2" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer" >Chassi</label>
 </div>



<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4">
<input class="form-check-input  RRFrom RRFromRow1  " type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow1[]" id="RRFromRow1" value="RR" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="RRFromRow1" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer">Rail Road</label>
 </div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4 ">
<input class="form-check-input ChassiFromRow1" type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow1[]" id="ChassiFromRow1" value="ZZ" style="cursor:pointer">
  <label for="ChassiFromRow1" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer" >Chassi</label>
 </div>
```

// html

Please note : the other Classes .RRFrom are NOT at the same group , actually they are in different divs too, but holding same Class name.

Also please I do not need to use removeAttr()  because this will not allow me to check the radio button again!!

Comment: Can you please send your html

Comment: Also add your HTML code.

Comment: If they're all the same class then you can use the class to select them

Comment: I couldnt Select classes , it is not working that way, I need to use Siblings Maybe

Comment: Are you wanting the whole group of radios that includes one with `.RRFrom` to be unchecked?

Comment: Yes thank you , its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the class, excluding the clicked element with `.not(this)`

Working snippet:

```js
$('.RRFrom').click(function(){
   $('.RRFrom').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4">
<input class="form-check-input  RRFrom RRFromRow2" type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow2[]" id="RRFromRow2" value="RR" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="RRFromRow2" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer">Rail Road</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4 ">
<input class="form-check-input ChassiFromRow2" type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow2[]" id="ChassiFromRow2" value="ZZ" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="ChassiFromRow2" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer" >Chassi</label>
 </div>



<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4">
<input class="form-check-input  RRFrom RRFromRow1  " type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow1[]" id="RRFromRow1" value="RR" style="cursor:pointer">
<label for="RRFromRow1" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer">Rail Road</label>
 </div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ml-4 ">
<input class="form-check-input ChassiFromRow1" type="radio" name="RRZZFromRow1[]" id="ChassiFromRow1" value="ZZ" style="cursor:pointer">
  <label for="ChassiFromRow1" class="form-check-label col-form-label col-form-label-sm" style="cursor:pointer" >Chassi</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Still Not working , I need to check one radio button then the others (with different group must unchecked )

Comment: @bilal The two radios labeled "Rail Road" are the only one's with `.RRFrom` class, You will see if you run the snippet and check one then the other will uncheck if it is checked

Comment: correct , I know , but i need to add more divs to this code same way , and on those particular classes i need only to unchecked them all when i check on  one, so if i check a Rail Road all others Rail Roads must unchecked